# RichFaces 4.3.7 in Jboss EAP 7.0.9 : IllegalStateException

Tags: java, richfaces, jboss-eap-7

We are having issues with application having RichFaces 4.3.7 in Jboss EAP 7.0.9.
This application works fine in Weblogic 12c.

Now when this application is deployed in jboss eap 7.0.9, we are getting below issues.

We were seeing below issues
2018-08-02 10:27:32,356 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-3) UT005023: Exception handling request to /pcc/policysearch: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl.assertNotReleased(FacesContextImpl.java:712)
    at com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl.getExternalContext(FacesContextImpl.java:141)
    at com.thehartford.pl.agency.pcc.controller.PlassController.(PlassController.java:45)
    at com.thehartford.pl.agency.service.servlet.PCCLoginServlet.doPost(PCCLoginServlet.java:54)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at com.thehartford.pl.agency.pcc.filter.CrossScriptingFilter.doFilter(CrossScriptingFilter.java:63)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.mod_cluster.undertow.metric.RunningRequestsHttpHandler.handleRequest(RunningRequestsHttpHandler.java:69)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:285)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:264)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:175)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:324)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:803)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

removing richfaces related jar from application library, helped to stabilize  the application. But richfaces related functionalities are not working now.

Any help will be very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was resolved when i build the application with RichFaces 4.5.9